# Character encoding annoyance

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am suddenly getting a character encoding error when trying to run ant build-all. I have been in the properties for my project, and choose UTF-8 under resource. Still I'm getting the following error (actually there are more than 100 encoding errors) when trying to build-all:

```
error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[javac]         //  nedenfor inden f�rste angreb, s� total = 41 = tur 21
```

I cannot commit my project because of this error. Any idea how to fix this? And it just all of a sudden started complaining about encoding

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to specify the `encoding` argument on your Ant `javac` task:

```xml
<javac encoding="UTF-8" ...
```

Ant tasks do not know about Eclipse project properties.